# Dynamic creation of percentages for each column in r

Tags: r, dplyr

I have the following data:

```
library(dplyr)
group_1 <- c(1,1,2,2,1,1,2,2)
group_2 <- c("A","A","A","A","B","B","B","B")
val <- c(sample(8))
xyz <- c(sample(8))
abc <- c(sample(8))
def <- c(sample(8))
ab23 <- c(sample(8))

df <- data.frame(group_1,group_2,val,xyz,abc,def,ab23)

df <- df %>% group_by(group_1,group_2) %>%
      mutate(val_per = val/sum(val,na.rm = TRUE),
             xyz_per = xyz/sum(xyz,na.rm = TRUE),
             abc_per = abc/sum(abc,na.rm = TRUE),
             def_per = def/sum(def,na.rm = TRUE),
             ab23_per = ab23/sum(ab23,na.rm = TRUE))
```

I don't want to mutate new columns for creating percentages for each column. Is there a way in which new columns are create which have the percentage for each column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with `across` -

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(group_1,group_2) %>%
  mutate(across(.fns = prop.table, .names = '{col}_per')) %>%
  ungroup

#  group_1 group_2   val   xyz   abc   def  ab23 val_per xyz_per abc_per
#    <dbl> <chr>   <int> <int> <int> <int> <int>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>
#1       1 A           4     5     2     3     1   0.667   0.714   0.222
#2       1 A           2     2     7     6     3   0.333   0.286   0.778
#3       2 A           8     4     3     7     7   0.889   0.364   0.429
#4       2 A           1     7     4     1     5   0.111   0.636   0.571
#5       1 B           5     6     5     2     8   0.455   0.857   0.455
#6       1 B           6     1     6     5     6   0.545   0.143   0.545
#7       2 B           7     8     8     4     2   0.7     0.727   0.889
#8       2 B           3     3     1     8     4   0.3     0.273   0.111
# … with 2 more variables: def_per <dbl>, ab23_per <dbl>
```

`prop.table(x)` is same as `x/sum(x)`.

Answer (score 2):

We can also do this:

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

df %>%
  bind_cols(df %>% 
              select(!starts_with("group")) %>%
              map_dfc(~ .x / sum(.x)) %>% 
              set_names(paste(names(.), "_per", sep = "")))

  group_1 group_2 val xyz abc def ab23    val_per    xyz_per    abc_per    def_per   ab23_per
1       1       A   3   4   1   4    5 0.08333333 0.11111111 0.02777778 0.11111111 0.13888889
2       1       A   2   2   6   8    2 0.05555556 0.05555556 0.16666667 0.22222222 0.05555556
3       2       A   8   8   7   3    3 0.22222222 0.22222222 0.19444444 0.08333333 0.08333333
4       2       A   5   7   8   5    6 0.13888889 0.19444444 0.22222222 0.13888889 0.16666667
5       1       B   6   5   4   2    4 0.16666667 0.13888889 0.11111111 0.05555556 0.11111111
6       1       B   4   1   5   7    8 0.11111111 0.02777778 0.13888889 0.19444444 0.22222222
7       2       B   7   6   2   6    7 0.19444444 0.16666667 0.05555556 0.16666667 0.19444444
8       2       B   1   3   3   1    1 0.02777778 0.08333333 0.08333333 0.02777778 0.02777778
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `proportions`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  group_by(across(starts_with('group'))) %>%
  mutate(across(everything(), proportions, .names = "{col}_per")) %>% 
  ungroup
```

-ouptut

```
# A tibble: 8 x 12
  group_1 group_2   val   xyz   abc   def  ab23 val_per xyz_per abc_per def_per ab23_per
    <dbl> <chr>   <int> <int> <int> <int> <int>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>    <dbl>
1       1 A           2     2     3     2     7   0.286   0.2     0.273   0.286    0.7  
2       1 A           5     8     8     5     3   0.714   0.8     0.727   0.714    0.3  
3       2 A           4     1     2     8     1   0.364   0.2     0.667   0.667    0.333
4       2 A           7     4     1     4     2   0.636   0.8     0.333   0.333    0.667
5       1 B           6     3     5     7     8   0.857   0.3     0.556   0.875    0.571
6       1 B           1     7     4     1     6   0.143   0.7     0.444   0.125    0.429
7       2 B           8     6     7     3     4   0.727   0.545   0.538   0.333    0.444
8       2 B           3     5     6     6     5   0.273   0.455   0.462   0.667    0.556
```